# ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=3 Authentication needed

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest ,while i can use safari or firefox to get response,asihttprequest return ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=3  Authentication needed,anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Your request should have a username and password of the server that you are attempting to access.

Add the following code in your request :

```
[request setUsername:@"test"];
[request setPassword:@"test123"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the user-agent of the API or website you are requesting. The useragent will not be the same as safari.

You can alter the user-agent like so:

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"];
```

Comment: Then it must be something else. Could you reveal your request code ? it would give much better insight in what might go wrong.

Comment: i fixed the problem, it read ResponseHeaders ,my server's response code for 401 is SESSION_KEY_INVALID while the asihttprequest will return ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=3 Authentication needed for 401

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, because i have mistyped the parameter name in setPostValue:forKey: